# How to display name and surname of the employee with updated salary?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-update, database-trigger

SQL Developer displays an error about mutation. 
Could You give any advice how to deal with it? 
I am logged as hr user on Oracle 11g.

```
create or replace trigger displayEmp
before update ON employees
for each row
declare
    v_name varchar;
    v_surname employees.last_name%type;
    newSal employees.salary%type;
begin
    newSal := :new.salary;
    select first_name, last_name into v_name, v_surname 
    from employees where salary = newSal;
    dbms_output.put_line(v_name || ' ' || v_surname);
end;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just display the name and surname of the employee that is being modified?

Comment: Yes, I want to display the employee whose salary was updated.

Comment: Triggers are not to be used as a display mechanism.  That makes no sense. your select is selecting ALL employees with a matching salary.  you should instead have a DATE field on the table such as "last updated" or even a salary history table. and query that.

Comment: So, is there any solution for the example above? Is that possible to display it in trigger? Some examples from stackoverflow shows it is, but that was t-sql trigger instead of pl/sql :/

Comment: The solution is to not use a trigger to do this.  Read my comment again.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of your trigger does not make a lot of sense, since it only prints some derived information to the standard output.

However, you seem to be overcomplicating this. To access the employee name, you don't need to query the table: that information is available in pseudorecord `:new`. This vastly simplify your code:

```
create or replace trigger displayEmp
before update of salary on employees
for each row
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(:new.first_name, || ' ' || :new.last_name);
end;
```

Note that I modified the trigger so it fires only when `salary` is updated: `before update of salary on employees`.

Comment: I got an error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges. I fire the trigger in live oracle sql.

Comment: @adan96ful: then you need to check if your user has the permission to create a trigger and to access the relevant database table. This is an authorization issue, not related to the trigger code.